# Many-to-Many Self Join on Symfony2 Entity Repository DQL

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

I have 2 Entities: user and recipe. User is associated with Recipe (One-to-Many) and user is Many-to-many self referenced: $cookingBuddies and $cookingBuddiesWithMe. I want to have a query that shows the recipes of the logged-in user's friends(something like Facebook's news feed). I have already my sql code:

```
SELECT r.*, u.* FROM user u INNER JOIN recipe r ON r.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id IN (SELECT user_id FROM cookingbuddies WHERE cookingBuddy_id=1)
OR
u.id IN (SELECT cookingBuddy_id FROM cookingbuddies WHERE user_id=1)
```

ORDER BY r.dateAdded DESC`

My problem is that cookingbuddies( which is the generated join table by symfony) gets an error because i have no entity for it.

Here's my code for the repository:

```
function findByTime($id) {
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT r FROM user u INNER JOIN recipe r WITH r.user_id = u.id WHERE  u.id IN                
   (SELECT user_id FROM cookingbuddies WHERE cookingBuddy_id=1) OR u.id IN (SELECT cookingBuddy_id FROM cookingbuddies WHERE user_id=1) ORDER BY r.dateAdded DESC');$query->setParameter('id', $id);

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

How do you translate that to DQL? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do a sub query to use your `ManyToMany` relationship in the DQL, just query against it directly:

```
SELECT u, cb, re FROM MyBundle:User u JOIN u.cookingBuddies cb JOIN cb.recipes re WHERE cb = :buddies
```

You can also use directly your entities getters, but depending on your setup it will be less efficient:

`$user->getCookingBuddies()->getRecpies()`